# Change order of text in a variable within SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sorting, variables, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a SQL stored procedure that has a dynamic variable. The variable is used to create a comma separated list of field names that get used to generate a pivot table.

When executed, the variable might have the values:

```
[Qty Actual - Week 1], [Qty Actual - Week 2], [Qty Actual - Week 3],
[Qty Budget - Week 1], [Qty Budget - Week 2], [Qty Budget - Week 3],
[Qty Shipped - Week 1], [Qty Shipped - Week 2], [Qty Shipped - Week 3]
```

The end result of the pivot is exported to Excel, and the fields come out in the order above. However, I want them to come out like this:

```
[Qty Actual - Week 1], [Qty Budget - Week 1], [Qty Shipped - Week 1]
[Qty Actual - Week 2], [Qty Budget - Week 2], [Qty Shipped - Week 2]
[Qty Actual - Week 3], [Qty Budget - Week 3], [Qty Shipped - Week 3]
```

I would have to change my entire stored procedure the way I have setup at the moment. Is there some command that I can use to change the order of the columns within a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @TAB_VAR
SELECT @VAR

INSERT INTO @TAB_VAR1
SELECT SPLIT.A.VALUE('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM   (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(COL, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS DATA
        FROM   @TAB_VAR) AS A
       CROSS APPLY DATA.NODES ('/M') AS SPLIT(A)
ORDER  BY SUBSTRING(SPLIT.A.VALUE('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), LEN(SPLIT.A.VALUE('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) -  1, 1)

SELECT @VAR = ''

SELECT @VAR = COALESCE(@VAR+',', '') + COL
FROM   @TAB_VAR1

SELECT @VAR
```

Comment: DECLARE '@var' varchar with your input and DECLARE '@tab_var' and '@tab_var1' TABLE variable with col VARCHAR(8000)

Comment: i wasn't able to add these code in answer area so added here